# How to replace the index of elements of a list with some other numbers?

Tags: python, list, enumerate

I have a list of elements, Let's say something like below:

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

by using the `enumerate` function, I'll get a list like below:

```
B = [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)]
```

But I want to replace the indexes with a given list of numbers, for example:
if I have a list like below:

```
C = [4, 6, 9, 10 , 22]
```

I want to change the B to a list like below:

```
B_modified = B = [(4, 1), (6, 2), (9, 3), (10, 4), (22, 5)]
```

How can I do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the `zip` function to combine these two lists.

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
C = [4, 6, 9, 10 , 22]

B = list(zip(C, A))

print(B)
```

Output:

```
[(4, 1), (6, 2), (9, 3), (10, 4), (22, 5)]
```

It can be used just like `enumerate`:

```
for i, e in zip(C, A):
    print(i, e)
```

Output:

```
4 1
6 2
9 3
10 4
22 5
```